# Braces of stix package into another package

Tags: stix

```
      \documentclass[12pt]{article}
     \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
     \DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
      \DeclareSymbolFont{xlargesymbols}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}
   \DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{operators}{"7B}{xlargesymbols}{"00}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{operators}{"7D}{xlargesymbols}{"01}

  \begin{document}
  \textbf{Question.} $A=\{x \ : \ x>0\}$. 
   \end{document}
```

I am getting such weired output

[image]

What has happened? Where have i gone wrong? Can anyone help

Comment: the code for the second formula is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You think something like this is suitable? I loaded the T1 table font for `stix` and browsed through the tables to use the proper fonts. I then inserted the code. You can see the new symbol being used

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\makeatother
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}

\DeclareSymbolFont{xlargesymbols}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{xop}{LS2}{t1-stixgeneral}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{xop}{"5E}{xlargesymbols}{"0C}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{xop}{"2F}{xlargesymbols}{"01}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Question.} $A=\{x \ : \ x>0\} (ab)$. 

\[
A=\left\{\frac{a}{p}\right\} \left(\frac{a}{B}\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]